# Wrapping a H2 tag inside another H2 tag?

Tags: html, seo

Is it bad practice in terms of SEO to wrap a H2 tag inside another H2 tag like so or is this still a valid method of displaying h2 tags :

```
<div class="content-caption light-content">
    <h2 class="open-project-link">
        <a class="open-project" href="work01.html">
            <h2 class="section-info">Branding</h2>
        </a>
    </h2>
</div>
```

Or will you be disciplined by google and will your SEO take a hit?

Comment: Better to do this you can change `<h2 class="section-info">Branding</h2>` to `<span class="section-info">Branding</span>`

Comment: This would be bad practice. I am trying to understand in what context this is useful.

Comment: This breaks the semantic meaning of the document and hence is bad practice. Also, the HTML spec forbids it and browsers will render it as sequential headings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to nest H2 elements. The [HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sections.html#the-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-and-h6-elements) forbids it. Error recovery will either give you sequential headings or ignore one entirely (triggering it is foolishing though).

> Content model: Phrasing content.

[Phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#phrasing-content) does not include headings.

It doesn't make sense to try to do so in the first place though.